# Set Parent product to all products

Tags: sql-server

I'm wanting to get the same Parent product to all ticket rows

query:

```
      SELECT  ID      
      , ID_Prod
      , Desc_Product
      ,(case when Desc_Product LIKE '%delivery 1%' then 'delivery 1'         
      when Desc_Product LIKE '%delivery 2%' then 'delivery 2'
      else 'shop' end)  
      as Parent_product
      from products 
      where ticket = '384995'
```

I have this:

```
ID  Ticket  ID_Prod         Desc_Product            Parent_product
137 384995  1               product 1               shop
137 384995  2               product 2 delivery1     delivery 1
137 384995  3               product 3               shop
137 384995  3               product 3               shop
137 384995  4               product 4               shop
137 384995  4               product 4               shop
137 384995  4               product 4               shop
137 384995  4               product 4               shop
```

But I need somenthing like:

```
ID  Ticket  ID_Prod Desc_Product            Parent_product
137 384995  1       product 1               delivery 1
137 384995  2       product 2  delivery1    delivery 1
137 384995  3       product 3               delivery 1
137 384995  3       product 3               delivery 1
137 384995  4       product 4               delivery 1
137 384995  4       product 4               delivery 1
137 384995  4       product 4               delivery 1
137 384995  4       product 4               delivery 1
```

Answer (score 0):

from what i understand if one product has delivery 1 all the other products shoud return delivery 1 and same goes for delivery 2 ,in that case this the answer i came up with:

```
    SELECT  ID      
          , ID_Prod
          , Desc_Product
          ,(case when exists 
                  (select prods.Desc_Product
                  from products prods
                  where prods.ID =products.ID 
                  and prods.Desc_Product LIKE '%delivery 1%' ) 
            then   'delivery 1'
            case when exists (select prods.Desc_Product
                              from products prod
                              where prod.ID =products.ID 
                              and prod.Desc_Product LIKE '%delivery 2%' ) 
            then   'delivery 2'
            else 'shop' end)
          as Parent_product
          from products 
          where ticket = '384995'
```